# How do I disable the touchscreen drivers?

Tags: mouse, touchscreen

I have a touchscreen, but the drivers are not working properly and interfere with my mouse.

Is it possible to disable my touchscreen , so that I can work again properly?

Comment: I have the same problem although the touchscreen is working perfectly, but the reason is my old year old touching on the screen while I try to work :)

Comment: Related: I added an answer to disable the _trackpad_ on Ubuntu 22.04 from the command-line here: [How to enable/disable the touchpad in Ubuntu 22.04 from the command-line](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446479/327339)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can try disabling the input device with the `xinput` command. First see what input devices you have, just type:

```
xinput
```

And you should see a list like:

```
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
...
```

Then you can disable the input device you want with this command:

```
xinput disable 9
```

Where 9 is the id of the device you want to disable. You can also use the device name between quotes.

In xinput version 1.5.99.1 , you need to do `xinput set-prop 9 'Device Enabled' 0` instead. Oddly on xinput v1.6.2 the first way work.

Comment: This works on my lenovo yoga (2012) running ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Works on Dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu 16.04. I also added this to `~/.profile` to auto apply after reboots: `xinput | grep 'ELAN Touchscreen' | grep -Po 'id=\d+' | cut -d= -f2 | xargs xinput disable`

Comment: Atmel also seems pretty common, an alternative way as @TalkLittle: `xinput enable \`xinput | grep Atmel | sed "s/^.*id=\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/"\``. Command inside What does backticks return the id.

Comment: Thank you. works on dell inspiron 13 7000 series running Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: This is a gt on reat option. I prefer a way to turn i

Comment: Alternative to @TalkLittle and @PabloBianchi solutions: `xinput | grep "SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen" | awk '{match($0,"id=([0-9]+)",matches)}END{print matches[1]}' | xargs xinput disable`

Comment: Alternative to all of the above: `xinput disable $(xinput list --id-only "[Entire touch device name]")`

Comment: I've scripted this and attached it to a shortcut, **Ctrl + Alt + P**, here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1206493/327339

Comment: Works on Lenono Yoga 500 Ubuntu 18

Comment: This works on my Lenovo Yoga-730 15iwl on Ubuntu 20.04: `xinput disable \`xinput --list | grep -i 'touch ' | sed 's/id=//g' | cut -f2\``

Comment: Thank you! On my Hp Elitebook G3 1040 this worked:

`book:~$ xinput`
`⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]`
...
`⎜   ↳ ATML1000:00 03EB:8A7F                    id=14 [slave  pointer  (2)]`
...
`⎜   ↳ ALP0013:00 044E:120A Touchpad            id=17 [slave  pointer  (2)]`
...
`⎣ Virtual core key...`
`book:~$ xinput disable 14`
`book:~$ xinput disable 17`

As you see the device 14 has NO Description, it came very handy to disable the touchpad, because sometimes during typing it reacts to input...

Answer (score 38):

The `xinput` solution did not work for me. I instead followed the instructions in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2209083&highlight=disable+touchscreen). This will disable it at boot time.

1. Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`
2. Add `Option "Ignore" "on"` to the end of the section with the `touchscreen` identifier
3. Reboot

[image]

- For the record (Google), I have a Samsung Series 7 and my touch screen was listed as `ELAN Touchscreen` in `xinput`.
- JFTR too, [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670092/does-disabling-touchscreen-have-any-impact-on-battery-life) says the power consumption difference is mostly negligible.

Comment: Thanks, it worked on my XPS 13 9343 (2015), the touch screen was listed evdev touchscreen.

Comment: This worked on my lenovo yoga (2012).

Comment: I did that on a Dell XPS and it disabled the screen completely. After booting the screen is just black. Booted in recovery mode, removed the line and everything went back to normal.

Comment: This prevented my laptop for rebooting into X windows. Not a big deal to remove that setting, but something newbies want to check they can do before trying it.

Comment: FYI to future users (and self): This no longer works on my lenovo yoga. It gives the same problem that @pieroxy experienced.

Comment: Same problem on asus taichi, x fails to load completely

Comment: I have added this suggestion on my x1 carbon. I thought I had everything setup while working with my external monitor and usb mouse with the laptop closed. But the next time I booted up without my external setup, the trackpad did not work.

Comment: Also disabled the touchpad on my Sony Vaio.  Setting the driver value to "libinput" did the trick though

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.10, I couldn't find the file you listed but there was `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`. I changed a similar block in this file and at next restart I guess I'll find out how it went!

Comment: Re: Oliv's comment - same thing on Debian 10.

Comment: @Oli Beatson';s worked for me Ubuntu 20..04 Ryzen 5 AMD . cracked screen. touchpad is ok .

Answer (score 8):

Edit file the file with

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
```

Change MatchIsTouchscreen from "on" to "off" in the Touchscreen section so it looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "off"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
    EndSection
```

Save, Name and Exit

Touchscreen is disabled and no longer detected in xinput list.

Comment: This worked on my Lenovo ideacentre Flex 20, which had a cracked screen.

Comment: This worked for Dell XPS 15 and Linux Mint 18. I think this is safer than using `Option = ignore` from the answer, as it doesn't disable the device just not doesn't treat it as a touch screen.

Comment: This isn't working anymore. I updated to Ubuntu 18.04, and the 10-evdev.conf file is gone. I tried recreating it, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Merlin04 Did you check the libinput file? There is an answer that mentions this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1038259/167115

Comment: For me, on linux mint the file to edit was `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

Answer (score 2):

As id for xinput changes on reboot, I added a simple one-line screen on session load:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput --list | awk '/Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer/ {print $7}' | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[2]}' | xargs xinput disable
```

My device's name is "Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer", change that with your device (use `xinput --list` for device name).

Answer (score 2):

## In order to disable the touchscreen on Ubuntu 19.x and 20.x you can:

- Wait the login screen
- Press Alt+F2
- Edit the "libinput" configuration and disable the touchscreen section, like that:

```sh
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

```sh
# Match on all types of devices but joysticks
#
# If you want to configure your devices, do not copy this file.
# Instead, use a config snippet that contains something like this:
#
# Section "InputClass"
#   Identifier "something or other"
#   MatchDriver "libinput"
#
#   MatchIsTouchpad "on"
#   ... other Match directives ...
#   Option "someoption" "value"
# EndSection
#
# This applies the option any libinput device also matched by the other
# directives. See the xorg.conf(5) man page for more info on
# matching devices.

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

#Section "InputClass"                               <----
#        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall" <---- this one
#        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"                    <---- put # in
#        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"        <---- front of
#        Driver "libinput"                          <---- every line
#EndSection                                         <----   

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

My "Dell Inspiron" touchscreen was broken. The cursor moved all over the place and click in random places several times a second. I was unable even to make login on the gnome or even to access the bios.

Answer (score 0):

If your touchscreen is a touch panel screen like a USB monitor, you can add default kernel driver `usbtouchscreen` into modprobe's blacklist file (`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`) and use your custom driver such as `touchkit` or `evtouch`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@romaia's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/232808/327339) shows, `xinput` is indeed the right way to do it.

However, I like to write a script and attach calling this script to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> keyboard shortcut, to make this super easy. Now I get an auto-closing window like this when I use this shortcut the first time:

[image]

...and if I use the shortcut again:

[image]

Ah, beautiful! Now I can easily enable/disable my touchpad or touchscreen, and fix mouse scroll speed, all with a single easy-to-use keyboard shortcut!

Get the latest version of this script here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/toggle_touchpad.sh.

Here's a snapshot of it at this moment:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# This file is part of eRCaGuy_dotfiles: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles

# toggle_touchpad.sh
# - toggle the touchpad & touchscreen on and off, and enable/disable imwheel to fix scroll speed when using a mouse
#   instead of the touchpad

# Gabriel Staples
# Started: 2 Apr. 2018 
# Update History (newest on TOP): 
#   28 Jan. 2020 - added in lines to disable Touchscreen too, as well as show ID numbers of 
#                  Touchscreen & Touchpad
#   22 June 2019 - added in the imwheel stuff to not mess up track pad scrolling when
#                  track pad is in use

# References (in order of progression):
# 1. negusp described xinput: https://askubuntu.com/questions/844151/enable-disable-touchpad/844218#844218
# 2. Almas Dusal does some fancy sed stuff & turns negusp's answer into a script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/844151/enable-disable-touchpad/874865#874865
# 3. I turn it into a beter script, attach it to a Ctrl + Alt + P shortcut, & do a zenity GUI popup window as well:
#    https://askubuntu.com/questions/844151/enable-disable-touchpad/1109515#1109515
# 4. I add imwheel to my script to also fix Chrome mouse scroll wheel speed problem at the same time:
#    https://askubuntu.com/questions/254367/permanently-fix-chrome-scroll-speed/991680#991680
# 5. I put this script on Github, and posted a snapshot of it on this answer here: 
#    https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers/1206493#1206493 

# `xinput` search strings for these devices
# - Manually run `xinput` on your PC, look at the output, and adjust these search strings as necessary for your 
#   particular hardware and machine!
TOUCHPAD_STR="TouchPad"
TOUCHSCREEN_STR="Touchscreen"

read TouchpadId <<< $( xinput | sed -nre "/${TOUCHPAD_STR}/s/.*id=([0-9]*).*/\1/p" )
read TouchscreenId <<< $( xinput | sed -nre "/${TOUCHSCREEN_STR}/s/.*id=([0-9]*).*/\1/p" )
echo "TouchpadId = $TouchpadId" # Debug print
echo "TouchscreenId = $TouchscreenId" # Debug print

state=$( xinput list-props "$TouchpadId" | grep "Device Enabled" | grep -o "[01]$" )

PRINT_TEXT="Touchpad (ID $TouchpadId) &amp; Touchscreen (ID $TouchscreenId) "
if [ "$state" -eq '1' ];then
    imwheel -b "4 5" # helps mouse wheel scroll speed be better
    xinput --disable "$TouchpadId"
    xinput --disable "$TouchscreenId"
    zenity --info --text "${PRINT_TEXT} DISABLED" --timeout=2
else
    killall imwheel # helps track pad scrolling not be messed up by imwheel
    xinput --enable "$TouchpadId"
    xinput --enable "$TouchscreenId"
    zenity --info --text "${PRINT_TEXT} ENABLED" --timeout=2
fi
```

## References (in order of progression):

1. negusp described xinput: [Enable/disable touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844151/enable-disable-touchpad/844218#844218)
2. Almas Dusal does some fancy sed stuff & turns negusp's answer into a script: [Enable/disable touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844151/enable-disable-touchpad/874865#874865)
3. I turn it into a beter script, attach it to a Ctrl + Alt + P shortcut, & do a zenity GUI popup window as well:
   [Enable/disable touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844151/enable-disable-touchpad/1109515#1109515)
4. I add imwheel to my script to also fix Chrome mouse scroll wheel speed problem at the same time:
   [Permanently fix Chrome scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254367/permanently-fix-chrome-scroll-speed/991680#991680)
5. I put this script on Github, and posted a snapshot of it on this answer here: 
   [How do I disable the touchscreen drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers/1206493#1206493)
6. Get the latest version of this script here! https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/toggle_touchpad.sh

Answer (score 0):

## In order to disable the touchscreen on Ubuntu (Xorg or Xwayland) you can:

- Wait the login screen;
- Press Alt+F3 to open a console;
- Find the correct device id
- Edit /etc/rc.local to disable the touchscreen device;
- Make /etc/rc.local executable and reboot.

```sh
$ cd /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch
$ ls -1
  0003:2A94:5241.0006         <- my touchscreen
  0018:06CB:7621.0001         <- my touchpad
  bind
  (...)
```

then, test it:

```sh
$ sudo bash
$ cd /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch
$ echo "0003:2A94:5241.0006" > unbind
$ killall -9 Xorg
```

Setup rc.local to disable it on startup:

```sh
$ sudo nano /etc/rc.local
  #!/bin/sh
  ls -1 /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch | grep 0003:2A94:5241 > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
$ sudo chmod +x /etc.rc.local
$ reboot
```

I did this way because:

- It doesn’t break my other multitouch devices;
- It is simpler and works on Xorg and Xwayland;
- The last 4 digits of the device change often on boot, therefore, I needed a solution that locate the correct device based on a simple rule;
- My Dell Inspiron 5557 touchscreen is broken in such a way that I can’t access the bios or use a graphics environment, therefore, I needed a console solution.