# Disabling touch screen only temporarily

Tags: screen, touchscreen, input, xinput

My touchscreen is cracked, so the pointer continuously clicks on the cracked area. That prevents me from using the computer normally.

I have tried the `xinput disable 'ELAN Touchscreen'` command, and even the one specific to the input number (though it should make no difference), yet whenever I do this, touch is re-enabled after only a few seconds.

Is there some way to disable the screen permanently until I decide to turn it on again (when I finally go to fix it)?

Comment: Did you try `xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Device Enabled" 0`

Comment: Yes, the screen continues to reset to enabled

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 13):

To first find the id of the device use:

```
xinput -list
```

From there find the name of the touch screen and then run:

```
xinput disable DEVICE
```

where DEVICE is the device name enclosed in quotes or its id.

Comment: how to reinable?

Comment: You can add an alias with `alias disable-touchscreen="xinput disable \\`xinput --list | grep -i 'touch ' | sed 's/id=//g' | cut -f2\\`"
`
enable it with the comand `xinput enable DEVICE`

Comment: On Ubuntu 21.04, this enables a magic mode where the operating system crashes instantly the next time you touch the screen.

Comment: Works great! `xinput enable DEVICE`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a touchscreen to test it but you could install `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

And try to disable the touchscreen like I did for my touchpad, there's a dedicated entry for touchscreen, just below touchpad:

[image]

Comment: My menu looks quite different in dconf-editor, and there is even no `settings-daemon`, and I can't find these settings elsewhere in the menu.

Comment: @MadsSkjern: Try `dconf dump / | grep -C6 touch` to find the touch properties

Comment: @SylvainPineau The touchscreen only has one setting for orientation-lock

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command, where $usbid is the ID of the USB device you want to disable:

```
echo -n $usbid | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

Or equivalently, run the following command as root:

```
echo $usbid > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

You can find the ID of your device by running the following command:

```
dmesg | tail -20
```

For me, I had to use usb1:

```
echo -n "usb1" | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

The following article has more information about manual driver binding and unbinding:
https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/

Comment: And how to enable it back?

Comment: @KamilDziedzic use the same command, just replace `unbind` with `bind`

Comment: If it would be so easy then I wouldn't ask :) The problem is that this doesn't work for me. It looks like usb device was bind again but touchscreen doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, that is how it works for me (I have a touch screen). Did you read through the article I linked to above?

Comment: How does one tell the USB ID of the touchscreen?

Answer (score 0):

For me, [bowmanb's answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers#answer-486919) solved the problem of how to disable touchscreen drivers in Ubuntu.

(Below story has some keywords for incoming searches, in case other people are having similar problems)

My touchscreen on my Samsung Series 5 isn't cracked, but I had been getting a strange bug randomly off and on for the last few months that I couldn't isolate.

Basically - **in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 the mouse would jump to the left side of the screen and start spamming click events**.

Very annoying when your dock is on the left side of the screen, and it starts randomly opening a lot of applications. ;)

Anyway - it finally started happening often enough that I isolated the touchscreen as the source of the problem. The above answer fixed it for me!