# Does disabling touchscreen have any impact on battery life?

Tags: power-management, battery, touchscreen

I hesitate about keeping my touchscreen disabled on my Ubuntu installation.

I disabled it by adding `Option "Ignore" "on"` to the
 `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` file :

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

---

Does disabling (or ignoring) the touchscreen extend battery life or does it have any impact ?

Comment: This is confused --- you have two questions here. The failing of disabling the touchscreen *and* the power one related to the title. Please split them into two...

Comment: No no the touchscreen disabling works fine. There is [multiple methods](http://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers) to disable touchscreen. It have put it here just for information on the method I used. I have edited my question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to check it. Install [`powertop`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Powertop):

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

and run it (I use an averaging time of 30s, use one that gives more or less constant values when the system is idle):

```
sudo powertop --time 30
```

[image: powertop output]

The power consumption is shown there --- try it with and without touchscreen and compare results. Although I suspect that @A.B. is right --- it will be mostly negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes. But you will not notice the difference.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.* ***;)***

Comment: Haha not worries I was expecting this answer thanks! Why "Technically yes" ?

Comment: @hg8 It is consumed slightly less power, technically speaking. =)