# How to disable 'Tap to click' on the login screen

Tags: gnome, login, touchpad, gdm, tap-to-click

Due to lots of chocolate cake getting into my computer my touchpad doesn't work very well (along with the rest of the computer) any more, so I have disabled 'Tap to click', however this seems to have only disabled it for when I am logged in, how can I do this for the login screen too (before I have logged in)? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post also in askubuntu:

[How do I disable the touchscreen drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers)

Basically, you got 2 shots:

- Edit the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` file and adding `"Ignore" "on"` to the end of the section with the touchscreen identifier
- Disable the xinput device (`xinput disable <number of device>`)

Regards

Comment: That is to do with touchscreen though, will it work for touchpads too?