# Unwrite file change that causes crash

Tags: boot, crash

I tried to disable my touchscreen for Ubuntu 15.10 using the first answer in this link:

[How do I disable the touchscreen drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers)

However, on reboot the OS crashes.  I'm pretty sure I just need to delete the 'Ignore "on"' line in the file I edited, but am not sure how to access it (dual boot in Windows right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the crash happens after the terminal sessions are set up you can also do a "control" "alt" "f1" and if it shows a login use your normal account to log into a terminal session.

Otherwise you can also do this from the option "try ubuntu" from a live DVD session. In the launcher you will have all your disks, mount the one that holds your OS by clicking it.  Editing is probably best done by going to a terminal session and using "sudo" as you normally would edit the file.