# How can I disable my touchscreen? Need help with terminal

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

I'm new to ubuntu. 
I'm trying to disable the touchscreen. 
The answer seems to be in this thread [How do I disable the touchscreen drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers), however I don't manage to do the suggested editing.

Can someone please tell me how to:

> > Add Option "Ignore" "on" to the touchscreen section so it looks like this:

Section "InputClass"
Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "evdev"
Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

Thank you!