# Ubuntu mouse cursor flickering & severe lag in Unity games

Tags: games, intel-graphics, cursor

I know that this is potentially something for the RimWorld forums, but upon launching the game, my system lags a lot (Ran fine in Windows 10, so not just my computer being a potato) and my cursor flickers and periodically disappears.

The cursor/lag is across my entire system, not just the game. There is no "Unknown Display" in my display settings.

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 on an HP Envy x360 with Intel HD integrated graphics on an quad-core i7.

EDIT:

This issue seems to affect all Unity games (Not the DE, the game engine)
Also, the mouse flicker issue can be fixed using `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false` as suggested in other Unity-related posts.
The lag is still severe though. Note that this is not an issue with my graphics not being good enough, as the games ran fine when I was using Windows 10.

Comment: This will probably get closed, but I have a similar issue on my mediabox running Lubuntu.  I tested this on my laptop which has dual NVidia/intel graphics cards, forcing it to run on the Intel card.  Runs fine in Windows, but it choppy and glitchy in Linux, even with proprietary drivers. I can only assume it's a Linux/Intel combo issue.

Comment: Disabling the touchscreen worked for me.
See https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers