# HP Spectre x360 Touch Screen Deactivation

Tags: hp, touchscreen

I am currently using a Spectre x360 13' with Ubuntu and I would like to disable the touch screen because sometimes the cursor gets stuck on the screen. Is there a practical way to do so?

Comment: Does this answer help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1038259/167115 ? If the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` does not exist, just edit the other file mentioned and reboot and see if that works. To comment back to me, just use @mchid in the comment so that I will get a notification. Thanks!

Comment: xinput disable touch_screen_id worked
Thank you @mchid !

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I will mark this as a duplicate of [How to disable touchscreen permanently on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038248/how-to-disable-touchscreen-permanently-on-ubuntu-18-04)