# Use nano to change an "on" to "off" line in read only file

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, read-only, nano

I am trying to change a value in this read only file (`usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`) in order to switch a touch screen off.

I have have found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers) explaining how to disable these touch screen drivers instructing me how to do this using nano. My problem is that I have never used nano before and am not understanding how to change the "on" in line 42 to "off".

[image]

[image]

Please can you show me how to use nano so that the "on" in line 42 becomes an "off" ?

I know that in order to open the editor I can use:

`sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

but from here I am lost on how to use nano to perform the task.

Comment: The file `40-libinput.conf` belongs to the `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` package, would not change the file directly. Changes made will be lost the next time the package updates. Better copying of the file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` first, and edit the copy.

Comment: Thanks @bac0n, I will do so.

Comment: To add to all the other answers and comments, it is well worth the time investment to learn how to use `nano`. It comes in handy for making edits from the terminal and won't take too long to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- in a terminal window, execute the command you have already demonstrated in your question

  - now you have the file opened in nano
- navigate within the text content with the *arrow keys*

  - place the cursor *behind* the part you want to modify
  - use the backspace key to delete characters
  - type what you want instead
- type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

  - at the bottom of the window a sort of "confirmation dialog" will appear

    - it will contain the file name (where to save)
    - and prompts for either `y` (yes, save indeed), or `n` (this would close nano without modifying the file (hint taken from @matigo's answer))
    - so if all is well then hit that `y`.
    - but wait, here comes the part with the confirming the filename to save to (seen in @PJ Singh's answer): so hit an <kbd>Enter</kbd> too
- Nano will close and you are back to the terminal window. You are done.

Answer (score 1):

After opening `nano`, you can use the arrow keys to get to the part of the file you want to change. Then, just like any other text editor, use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the characters you don't want, and any other key on the keyboard to add the ones you want. When you're done, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (for Exit). This will give you a message like this:

[image: Nano Save Prompt]

Press <kbd>Y</kbd> if you would like to save changes, <kbd>N</kbd> if you want to ignore the changes, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if you want to go back to editing the file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the arrow keys to navigate to the "on" text.
2. Use the <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to delete the text
   "on".
3. Type "off"
4. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> keys
5. You will see a question at the bottom:

   ```
   Save modified buffer?
   ```
6. Press the <kbd>Y</kbd> key.
7. Now you will see something like this at the bottom:

   ```
   File Name to Write: 40-libinput.conf
   ```
8. Finally press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and your changes will be
   saved.

Comment: Arrrrghhhh the Enter at the end!

Comment: @Levente, you sir(/ma'am) have a great sense of humour hahaha